# Installing jupyter using pip

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

First I install python-3.10.0a1-amd64.exe
then i install pip
.Then after , i use command **pip install jupyter** but unable to install and error comes out ,given below

python version : Python 3.10.0a1

python-path : C:\Users\Tushar jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310

Error:

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\python.exe' 'c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Tushar jain\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-knk4grqs\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (31 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.6.0
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting cffi>=1.0
    Using cached cffi-1.14.3.tar.gz (470 kB)
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Tushar jain\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zgxnglfn\\cffi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Tushar jain\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zgxnglfn\\cffi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Tushar jain\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-y6xmoorg'
           cwd: C:\Users\Tushar jain\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zgxnglfn\cffi\
      Complete output (19 lines):
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Tushar jain\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zgxnglfn\cffi\setup.py", line 131, in <module>
          if sys.platform == 'win32' and uses_msvc():
        File "C:\Users\Tushar jain\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zgxnglfn\cffi\setup.py", line 109, in uses_msvc
          return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')
        File "c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 225, in try_compile
          self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
        File "c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
          self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
        File "c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 312, in msvc14_get_vc_env
          return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 266, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
          raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\python.exe' 'c:\users\tushar jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Tushar jain\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-knk4grqs\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools It even tells you where to get what is missing. What is exactly the question here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required